# Magento Cron Timing Issue

Tags: cron, development

Hi I am using pleks sheduled task to run magento cron.

I would like to know if there something wrong with my settings below.

Plesk settings: */5 * * * *

Note that the */5 * * * * runs properly. while the second one which I've set to run at 01:00AM doesnt run at all

```
 <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <teser_productimport_fivelog>
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>teser_productimport/observer::fiveLog</model></run>
        </teser_productimport_fivelog>
        <teser_productimport_tenLog>
            <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>teser_productimport/observer::tenLog</model></run>
        </teser_productimport_tenLog>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Comment: Have you checked cron output? Does that function run manually?

Comment: if I change 0 1 * * * to */5 * * * * it works.

Comment: Your expression seems to be correct. Check the server timezone, and what you have setup in Magento, if the function is not getting fired at 01 AM. Have you checked the call over a span of more than 24 Hours?